# How to get dynamic part of currentRouteName in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, routes, ember-data

I need the dynamic part of the 'model/thing/1' segment of the URL, as I'm trying to access model data in the application controller from the model currently loaded in a nested route. Is there a way to access the dynamic portion of this URL, or is there another way to somehow access this data?

Comment: you receive it in the routes `model` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to display model data (or any data) somewhere else on the page (not in the current template) then you can use either [ember-elsewhere](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) or [ember-wormhole](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole).

To access route params you can inject private [routing service](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RoutingService.html) and use its `currentState.routerJsState.params` property. Property contains each available route params indexed by current route name like this:

```
{
   application: {},
   test: {
      model_id: "19"
   },
   test.nested: {
      nested_id: "1"
   }
}
```

For instance, to display current route params we need something along these lines:

controllers/application.js (can be component or any ember object)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

   params: Ember.computed('routing.currentState', 'routing.currentRouteName', function() {
       let allParams = this.get('routing.currentState.routerJsState.params');
       let routeName = this.get('routing.currentRouteName');
       return allParams[routeName];
   }),

   jsonParams: Ember.computed('params', function() {
       let params = this.get('params');
       return JSON.stringify(params);
   })
});
```

templates/application.hbs

```
<div>params={{jsonParams}}</div>
```

The other option would be to create a service and populate it with required data in `afterModel` hook in relevant routes.

services/data-service.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
});
```

Nested route:

routes/nested.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   dataService: Ember.inject.service('data-service'),

   afterModel(model, transition) {
      this.get('dataService').set('model', model);
   }
});
```

controllers/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   dataService: Ember.inject.service('data-service')
});
```

templates/application.hbs:

```
<div>{{dataService.model}}</div>
```

Since you probably do not want to display this data in all routes, then you can inject routing service and use `currentRouteName` property to decide when to show it.

Comment: This is perfect for getting the route parameters, although it returns it as a computed property and I need it as a string as I need to pass it into a findRecord. I'm going to try wormhole. Thanks!

Comment: YES. Wormhole works! You lifesaver. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the `model` hook is `params`, which contains what you are looking for.

This is explained in the guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-model

Example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('photo', params.photo_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to access the parameters in the application route or controller. Is this possible?

Comment: No. For obvious reasons. What if you navigated to / ?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if the reasons were obvious to me. Could you clarify? And what would be the problem with returning an empty string in that case, or something similar?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a dynamic parameter specific to a route be available outside that route. This is consistent with the way urls work on the web.

Comment: I get you. Do you have any suggestions on how to display model data in a header that only exists in the application template then?

Comment: Your application's route structure is very much tied to how you want your user to perceive the urls. If you want data from a specific route available in the header, your header probably belongs in that route. If on the other hand, you want that data in every route, it probably should be fetched in the route mapped to / (application or index). Maybe / should redirect to /:photo_id. It all depends on what your app is doing. I would need a lot more context to tell you how to structure your app.